# How to fix "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning book "Agile_Web_Development_with_Rails_5", then in code chapter "Check Out!" I have this error.

```
NoMethodError in Orders#new

Showing /home/chiencong/depot/app/views/orders/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

    <%= form_with(model: order, local: true) do |form| %>
       <% if order.errors.any? %>
         <div id="error_explanation">
           <h2><%= pluralize(order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

           <ul>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/orders/new.html.erb
```

Comment: If you want to comment code you can use this <%# if order.errors.any? %>and <h2><%#= pluralize(order.errors.count, "error") %> , you didn't commented actually

Comment: Can you also check what is the value of `order` ?

Comment: in `new` action i have : 
<div class="depot_form">
<fieldset>
<legend>Please Enter Your Details</legend>
<%= render 'form', order: @order %>
</fieldset>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

```
def edit
 @order = Order.find(...)
 # put byebug(install gem before) here and check why your variable is empty
end
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you are commenting the code in the wrong way you have to comment the ruby code view like this

```
<%#= pluralize(order.errors.count, "error") %>
```

Now comes to your problem you have to make variable instance variable in the controller to access it on view like this

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
end
```

In edit method

```
 def edit
   @order = Order.find(id)
 end
```

Now you can access @order on view so replace order.errors with @order.errors

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: The form is rendered with local variable. `<%= render 'form', order: @order %> `, `order` should work.

Comment: Ok get it, Is anything wrong in my answer. I mean, I am new on this platform so kindly let me know the reason of negative marking. Thanks in advance.